# jquery .dialog .jqprint repeating previous content

Tags: jquery, dialog, jqprint

I have a working dialog box that loads content correctly. 
The dialog also has a print button which executes `.jqprint` against the `DIV` in the dialog box. 
This prints fine the first time but every subsequent print command prints whatever was printed first. 
The dialog shows the correct *new* information. 
I added a `ALERT` button which also shows the old content.

```
$("tr[id^=contract_]").css("cursor","hand").live("click",function(e) { 
    var sContract = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    $("<div id=\"printthis\" style=\"border:1px; #ffffff solid;\"></div>")
        .load("_contractdetails.aspx?contract=" + sContract + "")
        .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                title: "Contract Detail",
                draggable: true,
                modal: true,
                width:900,
                height:450,
                buttons: { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close");    },
                           "Print": function() { $("#printthis").jqprint(); },
                           "ALERT": function() { alert($("#printthis").html()); }
                         },
                resizable: true 
        });
});
```

Why isnt `#printthis` recreated each time? 
Should I *destroy* the memory copy of `#printthis` somehow?
Is this a limitation of `.jqprint`?

Comment: Please mix `'` and `"` quotes so you don't have to do escaping orgies. You also need to use quotes in attribute selectors (they are not optional anymore in recent jQuery versions): `$("tr[id^='contract_']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the old div first - otherwise you use the same `id` twice which can result in lots of odd behaviour. Another solution would be only creating the div when necessary:

```
var div = $('#printthis');
if(!div.length) {
    div = $('<div id="printthis" style="border:1px; #ffffff solid;"></div>');
}
```

Besides that, you might want to open the dialog from the success callback of `load()` since otherwise you open the dialog with the old contents and then - a few moments later when the server response arrived - update it with the new contents.

Comment: Thanks @ThiefMaster, this led me to the solution. I added `$("#printthis").remove();` before creating the div.